# Running a https dotnet app in a docker container

Tags: .net, docker, https, ssl-certificate

I have a linux vm (OVH VPS Ubuntu 21.04) using NGinx and Docker containers. Nginx is set up to use https redirections for a domain and a sub-domain so:

https://www.mydomain.ext -> redirects to the docker container -> http://domain.ext:5000

https://app.mydomain.ext -> redirects to the docker container -> http://domain.ext:5001

So my problem is that even if both domain and sub-domain are using https, the actual docker container aren't. I investigated on how to run a docker container using https. It appears that you can create a certificate with command `dotnet dev-certs https ...` and `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` and then using docker-compose. That works in local but the point of using docker is to not have to install dotnet on the production linux vm.

So is there a way to run a https dotnet web app via a docker container, including the https certificate inside the dockerfile or inside docker-compose? Or an alternative without having to install dotnet on the actual linux vm?

Comment: "So my problem is that even if both domain and sub-domain are using https, the actual docker container aren't." – How would that be a problem? Since this traffic is entirely inside your VM there's no point in encrypting it IMHO.

Comment: You're saying there is no point to run the site on https as long as Nginx will use https that's good enough?

Comment: Yes. Or why would you want to encypt traffic that doesn't leave your VM?